# Switch between bluetooth devices on two laptops

Tags: usb, laptop, bluetooth

I don't know whether this is possible or not.

I have two laptops (one work and one personal) setup on my office desk. I have a screen connected to both which I switch between via an HDMI switcher.

I have a wireless keyboard and mouse and speaker which currently communicate via a usb bluetooth receiver.

Presently I just swap the receiver between each laptop.

Ideally (first world problem I know) I like the devices to switch over in just the same way as the HDMI screen does by using two different receivers.

Is that possible, maybe by setting a rule in control settings somewhere?

Comment: Do you have to pair the devices anew after moving the receiver, or do they stay paired to both laptops at the same time?

Comment: You could use a KVM device that does both HDMI and USB, on which you may plug the receivers. It depends on the devices whether you will need to re-pair them each time (perhaps not the case here by your description).

Comment: @grawity no they stay paired

Comment: @harrymc that might work - by trying to eliminate wires and increasing the number of wires - ha

Comment: Is the wireless keyboard/mouse really bluetooth (dongle-less, don't need a dongle if laptop already supports Bluetooth) or just a regular 2.4Ghz wireless receiver? If it's bluetooth, i'm not sure what the dongle is for (unless it doesn't have BT) ; if not, use a KVM like harrymc said. There is a lot of misconception between wireless devices and bluetooth devices that can also use a dongle if the host doesn't support bluetooth.

Answer (score 3):

As the receivers stay paired when switched from one computer to the other,
you could use a KVM device that does both HDMI and USB.

The receivers will stay plugged-in to the KVM so when switching computers they
will be automatically switched as well.

These kinds of devices can be easily found
[on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=kvm+hdmi+usb&ref=nb_sb_noss_1).

Comment: to follow on from this, I haven't yet bought the KVM, but sometimes when switching the bluetooth receiver between devices, the laptop won't wake up (sometimes it does). I have a wireless keyboard and mouse interacting with the receiver. Both have been marked in the power settings to wake up the laptop, but it doesn't always work?

Comment: That's another question that will need more details.

Comment: So two laptops, with a HDMI switcher to one screen. I use a wireless keyboard and mouse and to swap between the machines I swap the usb receiver between both laptops. The laptop with the closed lid does wake up on mouse move or keyboard tap but only if the receiver hasn't been used in the other machine before being switch back - does that make sense ;-)

Comment: With the right KVM you will not need to switch the usb receiver.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and ended up buying a new keyboard and mouse (less than $40 each) that allowed me to switch devices from the peripheral itself. They allow you to switch between up to 3 devices by clicking a key on the keyboard or clicking a button on a mouse. Currently, I am using the Logitech K380 for my keyboard and the M720 Triathalon for my mouse.